# Git ignore tracked temp files

Tags: git, gitignore, temporary-files

In linux, I am using git. I initialized git in a project that already I had been working. I am in two or more commits now. Now only I came to found that my project has lot of temp files made by the Text Editor '`gedit`'. That files ends with `'~'`

For ex.,

```
index.html~
```

and so on... Now I need to remove all the temp files from my project directory. So I added the following line in my .gitignore file.

```
*~
```

But it still tracks the temp files. What should I do for not to track those temp files in my repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

From here: http://blog.mikeski.net/blog_post/12

First, remove them from the filesystem (on Unix I do):

`find ./ -name '*~' -exec rm {} \;`

Then remove them with a BASH for loop

`for x in`git status | grep deleted | awk '{print $3}'`; do git rm $x; done`

If you're on Windows, switch to Linux...

Answer (score 0):

Add them to [ignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

If they are still untracked run this

```
git rm -r --cached <file>
```